# Reactjs - How to make components aware of the current view state?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, flux, reactjs-flux

Tools I'm Using: Reactjs 0.14.7, react-router 2.0.0 (Flux Pattern)

Note: I tagged Redux, just cause I got a hunch(I haven't used it) that what I'm experiencing might be one of the reasons people rave about it.

---

I understand that react-router already manages which parts of the 
component tree are currently in view and renders the components based on the state of the current view tree.

**Question:**

**But what if, based on the components in view, one component needs to know what other components are also in view and behave differently depending on what other components are in view(the view state)? What strategy would you suggest to allow components to be aware of the other components in view?**

**My Current Solution:**

I currently am trying to use the URL to infer this global state, and even parsing it and putting it into a store in order for components to be aware of the view state by listening to changes from that store.

**My Issue With This Solution:**

In a nutshell managing that view state with a store becomes a highly entangled process with extra actions sprinkled all over the code.

1) Actions must be called for any user event that change the route.

2) Action need to be fired when navigating outside of components(I think its much cleaner to keep action firing in components(feel free to debate that one).

3) You must also consider the back button(currently using react-router onEnterHooks to catch when that happens).

Yet I really like the concept of encapsulating the view state because I can imagine that it creates a nice mental model and also smarter components, **but just parsing the current URL and using a utility file to determine the current view state when needed, seems like a much easier/cleaner solution to manage then a store that contains the current view state.**

Answer (score 2):

Components should *never* need to know what other components are being rendered, that's one of the fundamental concepts of React. You're trying to extract the "view state" from your component tree, when **your component tree should be determined by your state**. If you're already using Flux, you need to keep that information in the store, where it will be made accessible to any component that subscribes.

Flux isn't about making development easier or faster for an individual, it's about enabling practices that make it easier to keep a mental model of what an application is doing. This might come at the expense of some simplicity.

Redux is a refinement of Flux that combines the multiple stores that can be subscribed to individually with a single large state tree, with different parts of the tree created by different "reducers" -- functions that take a state and an action and return a new state. It is exactly "a store that contains the current view state." What you describe is also a pretty good description of the type of development common in hacked together jQuery applications, the type of development React seeks to avoid.

Comment: -"components should never need to know what components are being rendered" - but what if a component needs to behave differently depending on which SIBLING component is currently in view? In my case particularly, I need to fire different actions from the same component depending on which sibling component is in view. The only solution I see if capturing the viewstate in a store or using the URL to determine the viewstate. Am I fundamentally seeing something wrong?

Comment: You are fundamentally seeing something wrong. Your parent component should have state that it uses to determine what children to render, which you can pass down into those children so they know what action to fire. Other than props and the render function, components have no way of communicating with each other.

Answer (score 1):

I think the core of your misunderstanding falls into how React component's should be layered.  It's a tricky topic, and re-aligning your thought process to accurately understand what is a state vs. prop in your model, is a unique challenge.

But the solution to this problem you are facing is simply to order your components more 'correctly'.

At a high level, each component should *only* care about the props that are passed to it, and not about anything else whatsoever.  However, which props are passed are determined by it's parent Component.  As a result, that parent can make those decisions, which then have an end result in the child.

As a simple but practical example;

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    funcA: function(){
        this.setState({propB: 'something new!'});
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
        <div>
            <ChildA propA={this.state.propA} funcA={this.funcA} />
            <ChildB propB={this.state.propB} />
        </div>
        );
    }
});
```

With this layout of concerns, ChildA is capable of handling user input, passing it to `funcA` which then impacts ChildB.  But all of this happens without the Child components knowing anything about one another whatsoever.